# Colored blocks and towers

Tags: statistics

> George got a big box from his parents. In this box are colored blocks.
> He has white, black, red, blue and orange blocks. These blocks are all
> exactly the same size and of he has the same amount of blocks for each
> color. George will build towers of $10$ blocks high. Two towers are
> equal if they have the same color on every level of the tower. How
> many different towers can George build?
>
> A. Without white blocks?
>
> B. With exactly $6$ white blocks?
>
> C. With two blocks of each color?

A. Is this just $4^{10}$?

B. Is this ${{10}\choose{6}} + 4^4$?

C. Is this $5!$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For C), we **choose** the $2$ positions (from the $10$) that will be occupied by colour 1. Then we choose the $2$ positions, from the remaining $8$, that are occupied by colour $2$. And so on.

For B), for **every** way of selecting where the whites will go, there are $4^4$ ways to fill in the rest. So you need to multiply, not add.

The answer to A) is correct.